# Is it not welcome to ask for clarification of a down vote?

Tags: discussion

On a question I posted yesterday, I asked for clarification after receiving a downvote without a comment. I do this, as sometimes voters feel like it should be obvious to me what is bad about my post, and after asking for it it generates indeed feedback. Today I found this comment of me being deleted. So is it not appreciated asking for clarification about votes?

I allways had the impression it is more like, Dvoters should be encouraged to give feedback on their downvote.

Comment: Voting can be strange on gaming.SE. Some people vote by counting the words, while some others vote on grammar and spelling or how easily the answer can be found on reddit or google. I've already tried in another Meta to encourage leaving a helpful comment for the OP (when a question needs to be fixed) but it'll likely never happen. You can ask for clarification, but don't expect too many nice responses. It'll probably even earn you another downvote for even trying to get a response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your comment asking for downvote clarification was deleted is probably because the comment was unnecessary. Leaving a explanatory comment can be helpful to clarify the specific reasoning for downvoting, but it's not obligatory. If there's no comment, you can safely assume that downvoters thought "this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" - this is the tooltip shown when you hover your mouse over the downvote button.

Sometimes that's all you need to know about a downvote. Personally, I try to leave a comment on most of my downvotes... but if a question obviously has not done a single bit of research, I'll just drop a downvote without commenting. After all, if the asker doesn't want to spend any time being clear and understandable, why should I? I'm guessing most of the downvoters on this site share a similar outlook.

Comment: In a similar, yet unrelated, question, why can I not downvote a comment? I have seen some extremely rude or unnecessary comments on answers I have given or questions I have asked, but because they cannot be downvoted it's like the people are getting away with being disrespectful with no consequences.

Comment: @GamingWithTalon If you see a comment that is disrespectful, please flag it so a moderator can take a look. Downvoting a comment wouldn't have any consequences to a user anyways; you don't get any reputation for comments.

Comment: Oh ok, didn't know that.Thanks.